# Dropbox: /delta and shared folders

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api, delta

I'm using the /delta feature to find whether anything has changed in the Dropbox account.

When I run it for the first time (till 'has_more' becomes False), it's fine. But when I run it again (with the cursor from the previous call), it shows a list of files. I run it again (without changing any file), and I still get the same list of files (although they hadn't changed). I figured that these files were in a shared folder. 
I tested again with a new set of files in that folder and I get the same result -- these files show up in the delta entries although they weren't changed.

What's wrong?

I feel this is a bug. Any way to get around it?

Edit:
Here's the code

```
def getDeltaEntries(self): #this function is a method of a class
    def _getDelta():
        delta = self.client.delta(self.cursor)
        entries = delta.get('entries')
        has_more = delta.get('has_more')
        self.cursor = delta['cursor']

        while has_more:
            delt = self.client.delta(self.cursor)
            entries.extend(delta.get('entries'))
            has_more = delt.get('has_more')
            self.cursor = delta['cursor']
        return entries
    #workaround: query for delta twice and if the result is the same both times, 
    #it implies there's no change

    ent1 = _getDelta()
    ent2 = _getDelta()
    if ent1 == ent2:
        entries = []
    else:
        entries = ent1
    return entries
```

Comment: Could you add your code?

Comment: We really will need to see code to help. In general, I've never seen the behavior you describe.

Comment: Are you changing the cursor on every call?  The behavior you describe sounds like you might be using an old cursor, rather than updating your cursor with the one returned after each /delta call.

Comment: Updated with the code.

Comment: @atwyman Yep. I'm updating it on every call. (See code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your code is using `self.cursor = delta['cursor']` when it should be using `self.cursor = delt['cursor']`.